# C# Filter Similar Table Records SQL

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, filter

There is a Seeker table, employer table, category table ,interest table..

Interest table stores interests of both seekers and employers, depending on their categories of interest... and uses Foreign Keys...

```
FK_is_id = Seeker ID
FK_ie_id = Employer ID
FK_ic_id = Category ID
```

So the data is stored like this:

```
int_id   FK_is_ID  FK_ie_ID  FK_ic_ID
1           2          null      3
2           2          null      5
3           null       1         3
4           null       3         1
5           null       2         5
6           4          null      1
```

Now, the table shows that Seeker 2 likes category 2 and 5

Employer 1 Likes category 3, employer 2 likes category 5, employer 3 likes category 1...

It also shows that seeker 2 and employer 1 has similar interests and seeker 2 and employer 2 also has same interests...

Seeker 4 and employer 3 has same interests..

So what i need is when depending on Seeker ID, display employers who has same interest as the seeker.

For example: if S ID (From Seeker Table) 2 is given then display that Employer 1 and Employer 2 has same interests as him!

Im using this code to list the employer names on webform.. So what im missing is the SQL Logic.. Any help is appriciated!

```
String ssid;
ssid = Request.Cookies["UserSettings"]["sid"];
SqlConnection myConn2;
SqlCommand myCommand2;
SqlDataReader myReader2;
String SQL2, divjobs;
myConn2 = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString());
divjobs = "<ul>";
myConn2.Open();
SQL2 = "";

myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(SQL2, myConn2);
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", ssid);
myReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();

while (myReader2.Read())
{
divjobs = divjobs + "<li>" + myReader2["e_name"] + "</a>" + "</li>";
}
divjobs = divjobs + "</ul>";
latestEmp.InnerHtml = divjobs;
myConn2.Close();
```

Comment: You've tagged with MySql, yet, you use `SqlConnection`, which is for Sql Server. Also, you've posted this [question before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27674168/c-sharp-filter-similar-table-records-sql/27674229)

Comment: Ah, i thought they both were same... 
& about the question, as i felt i didnt explain it enough, i deleted it and rewrote it in more detail hoping to get what i am looking for... Any help would be appriciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure of your RDBMS as per the comments above, but this [Sql Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/508273/1) will return the Employee Id data for the Searcher Id Subject (I've filtered for Student id 2). You haven't given us your employee or student table, so you'll need to join to these tables in order to extract fields like `e_name` from your reader. I've just pulled the `FK_ie_ID` foreign key below.

To pull this into your application, you need to bind the @sid parameter to the query. Also note that SqlCommands and Readers are IDisposable.

Finally, if your choice of RDBMS is MySql, not Sql Server, you will need to reference the appropriate MySql libraries and change `SqlConnection` to `MySqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` to `MySqlCommand`.

```
string SQL2 = "SELECT ins.int_id, ins.FK_is_ID, ine.FK_ie_ID" +
" FROM " +
"   Interests ins" + // For Seekers
"   INNER JOIN Interests ine" + //  For Employers
"   ON ins.FK_ic_ID = ine.FK_ic_ID " +
" WHERE " +
"   ins.FK_is_ID = @sid " +
"   AND ine.FK_ie_ID IS NOT null ";

using var (myCommand2 = new SqlCommand(SQL2, myConn2))
{
  myCommand2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", ssid);
  using (myReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader())
  {
    var sb = new StringBuilder;
    while (myReader2.Read())
    {
       divjobs = string.Format("<li>{0}</a></li>", (string)myReader2["FK_ie_ID"]);
    }
    divjobs = sb.ToString();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much the code is working fine... Thats exactly what i want to do.. and as i said, i need the e_name to print our.. 
I have e_id,e_name in employers table so if i Join it like this..  
`SELECT emp.e_name,ins.int_id, ins.FK_is_ID, ine.FK_ie_ID" + " FROM " + "   Interests ins" + "   INNER JOIN Interests ine" + "   ON ins.FK_ic_ID = ine.FK_ic_ID " + "FULL OUTER JOIN employers emp on emp.e_id=ins.FK_ie_id" + " WHERE " + "   ins.FK_is_ID = @sid " + "   AND ine.FK_ie_ID IS NOT null `

and myreader2["e_name"];

Its giving not printing out, but if i print out the FK_ie_id it prints out.

Comment: No don't full outer join to employer - replace with inner join. Also add emp.emp_name to the select list.

Comment: When i change to Inner Join nothing gets retrived, but with Full Outer Join it works fine... and what is the select list? If its the beginning portion i added emp.e_name there...

Comment: E_id is the primary key in employers page, FK_ie_id in application table has a relationship with e_id... I wonder where im wrong? :/

Comment: Aha - I see it - Inner join employers emp on emp.e_id = ine.fk_ie_id - ine not ins !

Comment: Im really sorry, i didnt get what you  meant.. If you figured it our? could you post the complete code again?

Comment: I removed all ine and replaced with all ins... and nothing seems to come up now... and changed to inner join

Comment: OMG.. Thank You, that fixed everything... I got exactly what i wanted... If i could +100 i would give it to you....

Comment: Would be great if you could help me a little here...
This code was to get employers who has same interest as the logged in seeker... Now i am trying to get employers who have same interest as the logged in employer, Kinda like competitors... I modified the code you gave me, and its giving me the desired output, but the result also includes logged in user's name as well... Is there a work around for that?

Comment: `SELECT ins.int_id, ins.FK_is_ID, ine.FK_ie_ID,ins.FK_ie_ID,emp.e_name,ine.int_id FROM  Interests ins INNER JOIN Interests ine ON ins.FK_ic_ID = ine.FK_ic_ID FULL OUTER JOIN employers emp ON emp.e_id=ine.FK_ie_id WHERE  ins.FK_ie_ID = @eid  AND ine.FK_ie_ID IS NOT null` < This is the modified code..